# What is difference between stochastic process and a sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose that I have a sequence of random variables $X=\langle X_1,...,X_n\rangle$ and I do not have any assumption about these continuous random variables, $X_i$'s, (they can be dependent/independent, identically distributed or not). Again suppose that $Y=\langle Y_1,...,Y_n\rangle$ is a stochastic process. Is there any difference between X and Y? can I say that X is also a stochastic process?

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: A stochastic process is a bunch of random variables defined on a common probability space. (And this was already asked on the site.)

Comment: I am still confused about what "common probability space" mean?

Comment: On THE SAME probability space (Omega,F,P).

Comment: does it mean that they are identically distributed?

Comment: No. To say that they are identically distributed, one usually says that they are identically distributed.

Comment: When r.v.'s are on the same probability space, it means that they have the same probability measure, is it different from identically distributed?

Comment: "it means that they have the same probability measure" No it does not. "is it different from identically distributed?" Completely. At this point, I suggest to check a few WP pages on the subject.

Answer (score 9):

> *Ahhh... A silent downvote, nearly four years after this was posted. So cute...*

According to the comments, there is a problem of comprehension at the heart of this question, which might be the following.

Consider a real valued random variable $Z$. This is a measurable function $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ between a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and the measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. The *distribution* of $Z$ (aka the *law* of $Z$) is definitely not the probability measure $P$, but the image of $P$ by $Z$, often denoted $P_Z$, that is, the probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ defined by the identity $\mu(B)=P(Z^{-1}(B))$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Thus, to declare that two real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ are *identically distributed* means that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $Y:\Phi\to\mathbb R$ for some probability spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and $(\Phi,\mathcal G,Q)$, and that the probability measures $P_X$ and $Q_Y$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ coincide. The fact that $P=Q$ or that $P\ne Q$ (both can happen) is quite unrelated.

To declare that two real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ are such that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ for some common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, as you seem to be intent on saying, one usually simply mentions that $X$ and $Y$ are *defined on the same probability space*.

Comment: I guess you mean $\mu(B)=P(Z^{-1}(B))$, $Z$ in place of $X$.

Comment: @Sultan Absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A sequence of random variables $X=\langle X1,\ldots,Xn\rangle$ could be also defined in the common probability space.  If $\{X_t, t\in T\}$ is a sequence of random variables, $T =\{1,2,\ldots, \infty\}$, but for a stochastic process $\{X_t, t\in T\}$, we could choose $T=[0,\infty)$ to interpret the process in continuous time and and $T=\{1,2,\ldots, \infty\}$ to interpret the process in the discrete time. The index set $T$ of a stochastic process can also be many other mathematical set.  A sequence of random variables is a special case of stochastic process. I think the difference is originated from the index set.

You can search item of Stochastic process in Wikipedia and get the similar result.

Answer (score -3):

If $X$ is a function of $X_i$ and if the $X_i$'s can take random values (like price, height, quantity, etc...), and $X$ is sorted by time, then $X$ is a stochastic process.

Comment: "If X is a function of X(i)" No.